# xamarin.form not buliding for android

Tags: xamarin

I created a new application in Xamrin.forms , PCL

but its android solution does not builds.

gets the following stack :
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter' available in SDK installer.
 Java library file C:\Users\sachin.manu\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter\23.0.1.3\embedded\classes.jar doesn't exist.
    XamarinHybridWebView.Droid

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r22.zip 
and extract it to the C:\Users\sachin.manu\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design\23.0.1.3\content directory.
    XamarinHybridWebView.Droid

and more , i am not even sure about the path referred , Is there any SDK missing ? I tried installing Fresh Xamarin still facing the issue, Any suggestions please ?

[attached build image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IrUR.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This generally happens during build because it is trying to download the android_m2repository_r22.zip.

It might be because of slow/no internet. However, you can follow these steps:

1. Download the [file](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r22.zip).
2. Create a new folder **content** within.

> C:\Users\sachin.manu\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design\23.0.1.3\

3. Extract the m2repository folder from the zip file and place it within the content folder.
4. Restart Visual Studio and try building again.

Happy Coding!